# Dropdown Bootstrap 3

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Como colocar um menu Dropdown do Bootstrap para exibir do lado direito?
Segue um modelo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Nossa, que modelo irritante! :-)

Comment: hahahahahahahhaha, Desculpa. Não foi minha intenção! Só pra ilustrar mesmo! kkkkkk

Comment: Agora sim! :) +1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Encontrei um exemplo no [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/chirayu45/YXkUT/16/) que com alguma adaptação acho que atende ao que você quer (acho legal e acho até que vou usar também :D). Coloquei no `snippet`, clique aí embaixo em **"Executar trecho de código"**, que já dá pra você ver funcionando.

```js
$(function(){
 $(".dropdown-menu > li > a.trigger").on("click",function(e){
  var current=$(this).next();
  var grandparent=$(this).parent().parent();
  if($(this).hasClass('left-caret')||$(this).hasClass('right-caret'))
   $(this).toggleClass('right-caret left-caret');
  grandparent.find('.left-caret').not(this).toggleClass('right-caret left-caret');
  grandparent.find(".sub-menu:visible").not(current).hide();
  current.toggle();
  e.stopPropagation();
 });
 $(".dropdown-menu > li > a:not(.trigger)").on("click",function(){
  var root=$(this).closest('.dropdown');
  root.find('.left-caret').toggleClass('right-caret left-caret');
  root.find('.sub-menu:visible').hide();
 });
});
```

```css
.dropdown-menu>li
{ position:relative;
 -webkit-user-select: none; /* Chrome/Safari */        
 -moz-user-select: none; /* Firefox */
 -ms-user-select: none; /* IE10+ */
 /* Rules below not implemented in browsers yet */
 -o-user-select: none;
 user-select: none;
 cursor:pointer;
}
.dropdown-menu .sub-menu {
    left: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    display:none;
    margin-top: -1px;
 border-top-left-radius:0;
 border-bottom-left-radius:0;
 border-left-color:#fff;
 box-shadow:none;
}
.right-caret:after,.left-caret:after
 { content:"";
    border-bottom: 5px solid transparent;
    border-top: 5px solid transparent;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 0;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 0;
 margin-left:5px;
}
.right-caret:after
{ border-left: 5px solid #ffaf46;
}
.left-caret:after
{ border-right: 5px solid #ffaf46;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="dropdown" style="position:relative">
 <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Click Here <span class="caret"></span></a>
 <ul class="dropdown-menu">
  <li>
   <a class="trigger right-caret">Level 1</a>
   <ul class="dropdown-menu sub-menu">
    <li><a href="#">Level 2</a></li>
    <li>
     <a class="trigger right-caret">Level 2</a>
     <ul class="dropdown-menu sub-menu">
      <li><a href="#">Level 3</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Level 3</a></li>
      <li>
       <a class="trigger right-caret">Level 3</a>
       <ul class="dropdown-menu sub-menu">
        <li><a href="#">Level 4</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Level 4</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Level 4</a></li>
       </ul>
      </li>
     </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Level 2</a></li>
   </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Level 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Level 1</a></li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente! Adaptei ao meu estilo! Tanks;)

Comment: Legal, agora muda aquela imagem! :-)

Comment: Andrew, não se esqueça de aceitar a resposta, para que a pergunta seja marcada como resolvida. É só clicar no sinal que fica abaixo da caixa de votação. Se tiver alguma dúvida, veja este tópico: http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/1078/como-e-por-que-aceitar-uma-resposta Abraços.